# How deep do the parallels with "The Lady who Loved Insects" run?

Tags: sakurako-san

Episode 1 of *Sakurako-san no Ashimoto ni wa Shitai ga Umatteiru* is titled 「骨愛ずる姫君」, translated by Crunchyroll as "The Princess who Loves Bones". To the Japanese reader, this is clearly derivative of 「虫愛ずる姫君」 ["The Lady who Loved Insects"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lady_who_Loved_Insects), an apparently famous narrative from the [*Tsutsumi Chūnagon Monogatari*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsutsumi_Ch%C5%ABnagon_Monogatari), a Heian-era collection.

Do the parallels between *Sakurako-san* (either episode 1 or beyond) and "The Lady who Loved Insects" run any deeper than just the title?

(I, like you, have read the Wikipedia article; my hope is that answerers will have read "The Lady who Loved Insects" or at least have more than a passing familiarity with it.)